# 2 footer rows in Datatable, 1 for filter, 1 for summ row

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, sum, footer

I am trying to have at the bootom of my table 2 footer rows. I for filter and another for sum. It is working separatlely, but not together. Thanks for help.
My suspicion is in method '.footer()' that try to display value into first row in footer.

```
<table id="vydana_faktura_seznam" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>ICO</th>
                <th>Jmeno spolecnosti</th>
                <th>Datum vystaveni</th>
                <th dt:sortInitDirection="asc">Datum splatnosti</th>
                <th>Spedice</th>
                <th>SPZ</th>
                <th>VS</th>
                <th>Castka</th>
                <th>Mena</th>
                <th>Vystavil</th>
                <th>Zaplacena</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <!--            search row -->
            <tr> 
                <th />
                <th />
                <th />
                <th />
                <th />
                <th />
                <th />
                <th />
                <th />
                <th />
                <th />
                <th />
            </tr>
            <!-- summ row -->

            <tr>
                <td />
                <td />
                <td />
                <td />
                <td />
                <td />
                <td />
                <td />
                <td class="footer_summ" style="text-align: right; padding: 8px 10px"></td>
                <td />
                <td />
                <td />
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#vydana_faktura_seznam tfoot tr:eq(0) th').each( function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Hledej '+title+'" style="width:100%" />' );
        } );

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#vydana_faktura_seznam').DataTable();

        // Apply the search
        table.columns().every( function () {
            var that = this;

            $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                    that
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                }
            } );
        } );
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#vydana_faktura_seznam').DataTable( {
             "footerCallback" : function ( data ) {
                    var api = this.api(), data;
                    // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation

                    var intVal = function ( i ) {
                        return typeof i === 'string' ? i.replace(/[&nbsp;]/g, '') * 1 : typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
                    };
                    // Total over all pages
                    var total = api
                        .column( 8 )
                        .data()
                        .reduce( function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0 );

                 // Total over this page
                    var pageTotal = api
                        .column( 8, { page: 'current'} )
                        .data()
                        .reduce( function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0 ).toFixed(2);

                    // Update footer
                    $( api.column( 8 ).footer() ).html(
                        pageTotal
                    );
                }
        } );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I solve my issue with help here
https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html